# Disable brotli compression for single nginx vhost

Tags: nginx, compression, gzip

I have a handful of websites on a single server, setup using https://serverpilot.io/

It enables brotli compression for all sites by default but I would like to disable this on a single site that sits behind a third party firewall that doesn't like the compression.

In `/etc/nginx-sp/vhosts.d/site-name.conf` I have tried

```
server {
    gzip off;
    gzip_vary off;
    brotli_static off;
```

I have also added these 3 lines `/etc/nginx-sp/vhosts.d/site-name.d/main.conf`

```
location / {
    proxy_pass      $backend_protocol://$backend_host:$backend_port;
    gzip off;
    gzip_vary off;
    brotli_static off;
}
```

However after a `sudo service nginx-sp restart` I'm still seeing

`content-encoding:br` in static asset requests

Answer (score 1):

Fixed with

```
brotli off;
brotli_static off;
```